# Cannot POST php mail (Vue)

Tags: php, vue.js

I am building a really small webapp in Vue with a simple contact form as component. I would like to use a really basic php script for sending the mail. I am not an expert on PHP but for some reason I can't figure out this bug I get when I try to submit the contact form. It says

`Cannot POST /mail_contact.php`

HTML/Vue component

```
<form class="contact" action="mail_contact.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">

        <input type="text" class="st-input" placeholder="Vul hier jouw naam in" name="name"> 
        <input type="text" class="st-input" placeholder="Vul hier kort en bondig jouw probleem in" name="problem"> 
        <input type="text" class="st-input" name="email" placeholder="Vul hier jouw e-mail adres in"> 
        <input type="text" class="st-input" placeholder="Vul hier jouw telefoonnummer in" name="tel">
        <select name="telOrEmail" required><option disabled>Maak een keuze</option><option value="Tel">Telefoon</option><option value="Email">Email</option></select>

    </div>

    <button class="send-button" type="submit">Verzenden!</button>

</form>
```

PHP Script

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //getters from form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $problem = $_POST['problem'];
    $telOrEmail = $_POST['telOrEmail'];

    //mail content
    $formcontent=" Van: $name \n Telefoonnummer: $tel \n Emailadres: $email \n Problem: $problem  \n Terugbellen of Emailen: $telOrEmail";

    //ontvanger van mail
    $recipient = "g.gijsberts@sqits.nl";

    //Onderwerp
    $subject = "Contact formulier Sqits-it";

    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

    echo "Bedankt voor je bericht! Wij hopen zo snel mogelijk te reageren.";

}

?>
```

Is there something I just don't see?

**Edit**
Project structure

- index.html (File)
- src (Directory) -> App.vue, main.js, router.js, components (directory) -> Contact.vue
- dist (Directory) -> build.js, build.js.map, index.html, mail_contact.php
- mail_contact.php (File)

So as you can see I've place my php script in the same directory as the main file (Index.html), but also in the directory where the build file is placed. Good point to say is this is a Vue project.

For a weird reason I get a 404 error (on localhost:8080/mail_contact.php) when submitting the form before I am redirected to the blank page with the `Cannot POST /mail_contact.php`. How is this possible if the file is actually there in my directory?

Comment: you need to check the directory path of mail_contact.php . as the error say , you are not pointing of the true path of your script in mail_contact.php

Comment: Do you mean checking if the mail_contact.php file is actually there? Because it is actually.

Comment: your `HTML` and `PHP` should be at the same directory

Comment: can you show you project structure ? .

Comment: one more thing i 'm seeing now , your button neead to have an attribut  name like :
    <button class="send-button" name= "submit" type="submit">Verzenden!</button>

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli I've updated my question with the project structure included.

Comment: you placed the php script on the same directory of index.html and the problem still here ?

Comment: Yes. Still no clue why it's not working.

Comment: umm, any idea but i found a link here : http://vegibit.com/developing-with-vuejs-and-php/ could you check it ?

Comment: Nope, not a solution for my problem. Just the weird thing is that It just can't the php file. Also tried to do an AJAX call but that is getting me also a 404 error.